# Use jQuery Plugins in React Component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Is there a way to use jQuery plugins in a react component?
if it is, can you give me a good example?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What plugin are you wanting to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cleanest" way to use jQuery inside React is using jQuery for all the things that do not manipulate the DOM(at all...)

For example, `jQuery.ajax` can be used to fetch data in small components (inside the `componentWillMount`.

Anything that alters the DOM is a big nono, as React handles the DOM in a very specific way(using JSdom).

Since a plugin can do anything really, it's hard to say which plugins can be used, but the anything that does not manipulate the DOM should be fine, although I'd still use it sparingly.